# Better query to get the list of products which have not had any sales in the last 90 days?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My code is super clumsy. Could you guys please provide a better way to get the result

Tables: Products & Orders

```
SELECT 
    Products.ProductID
FROM 
    Products 
    JOIN Orders
        ON Products.ProductID = Orders.ProductID    
WHERE 
    Products.ProductID NOT IN (
        SELECT 
            Products.ProductID
        FROM 
            Products 
            JOIN Orders
                ON Products.ProductID = Orders.ProductID
        WHERE 
            Orders.OrderDate >= DATEADD(day, -90, GETDATE())
        GROUP BY 
            Products.ProductID
)
GROUP BY 
    Products.ProductID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `NOT EXISTS` and no joins?

```
select p.*
from products p
where not exists (select 1
                  from orders o
                  where o.product_id = p.product_id and
                        o.orderdate >= dateadd(day, -90, getdate())
                 );
```

Comment: Hello Gordon, Thank you for answer. I am an absolute beginner. Could you please tell me what is the use of '1' after SELECT. Also, can I use  o.orderdate >= GETDATE()-7

Comment: @JithuKarthik A `select` statement requires a _select list_ of columns and/or expressions to return. When used within an `exists` the select list is ignored, but the syntax requires that you select something. `1`, `42` or even `NULL` will suffice.

Comment: @JithuKarthik . . . The `1` is the easiest thing to type, as Habo explains.  And yes, you SQL Server recognizes that a datetime minus an integer is to be interpreted as a number of days.  I would suggest that as a beginning, you don't use such shortcuts.

Answer (score 1):

I think using a CTE might give you a pretty straight-forward solution.

```
WITH CTE_ActiveList AS (

  SELECT DISTINCT
     O.ProductID
  FROM 
     Orders O 
  WHERE 
     O.OrderDate >= DATEADD(day, -90, GETDATE()))

SELECT P.ProductID from Product P
LEFT JOIN CTE_ActiveList L
ON P.ProductID = L.ProductID
WHERE L.ProductID IS NULL
```

Basically, you get a "list" of products that sold in 90 days.
and by applying this "filter" to the full product list to find out whichever product is not in this "list"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can invert your condition and instead select all products that had sales earlier that last 90 days instead?

```
SELECT Products.ProductID 
FROM Products
INNER JOIN Orders ON Products.ProductID = Orders.ProductId
WHERE Orders.OrderDate < DATEADD(day, -90, GETDATE())
GROUP BY Products.ProductID
```

This way it seems your subquery is all you need

Answer (score 0):

Try the below or just remove your whole subselect after join keeping just `select productid from products join orders on... And 
Orders.OrderDate >= DATEADD(day, 
-90, GETDATE())`

```
      SELECT 
       ProductID
       FROM 
       Products 
       Where ProductId Not In
        (Select 
        ProductID from orders
        WHERE 
        Orders.OrderDate >= DATEADD(day, 
         -90, GETDATE())
```

Comment: Hi,

Thank you for the answer. I just want to know if both these filters have the same effect

WHERE order_date >= dateadd(day, -90, getdate())

'and'

WHERE order_date >= GETDATE() -90

Comment: As far as its days addition it would be fine but else may perhaps become manual for you in case to calculate like months or years as days value on adding years or months